# How to authorise a transaction between two PayPal accounts?

Tags: angularjs, paypal

I am using AngularJS and have built a basic single page application. My users will enter in their PayPal email address and currency upon signing up and it will be saved within the database.

Any user can post something basic for sale for another user to purchase.

How can I authorise a transaction between two users PayPal accounts while keeping them within my site without a redirect to PayPal? All solutions online require the user to be redirected to PayPal.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use either [Reference Transactions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/) or [Preapproved Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicPreapproval-curl-etc/).

You can't avoid a redirect entirely if the users are going to be paying with the PayPal Wallet.  When they first sign up for your app/service they would need to authorize your system to make payments on their behalf.

So if you're using Express Checkout, for example, the user would be redirected to PayPal to authorize their account.  After that is done your app could then process payments using the DoReferenceTransaction API without the need for any redirection through PayPal.

The Preapproval API sets up the preapproval profile, so yes, at that point they would be redirected.  After that, though, you would have a preapproval ID that you would then pass into the Pay API in order to process payments for that person without any further approval (so no redirect) required.

If you're going to set this up with credit cards directly then you would need Payments Pro.  With that you could authorize a credit card directly within your app so you wouldn't need any redirect at that point, and then once again you would use a reference transaction to process payments for that card in the future.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. So either of those methods could be used without redirecting to the PayPal website?

Comment: Because step 2 of the Preapproved Payments states "Redirecting the customer to PayPal for authorization".

Comment: Thank you Andrew, your explanation is great. I believe Express Checkout would be the best way since when they sign up I can redirect them once and that's it. Does this have a callback that I can capture to make sure that they're payments are verified on my end?

Comment: Take a look at [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/).  Everything transaction that hits your PayPal account will send an HTTP POST of the transaction data to a listener URL you have setup.  Your URL/script can process that data however you need to, so you can automate all sorts of things based on various transactions in real-time.